# apiDoc Path Not Open after generating

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, rest, api-doc

After creating two routes like **user & auth** route in a node and express.js I generate apidoc documentation. It shows successfully generate **api_docs** folder -

[image]

But when I access the **apidoc** route then it show this error -

[image]

My **apidoc** module current version is **^0.28.1**
What's the problem was. I can't access the **apidoc** route path like - ***http://localhost:9100/apidoc/*** because of this error showing -

```
handlebars.min.js?v=1624725822600:29 Uncaught (in promise) EvalError: Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'".

    at e.Function (<anonymous>)
    at e.createFunctionContext (handlebars.min.js?v=1624725822600:29)
    at e.compile (handlebars.min.js?v=1624725822600:29)
    at e.compileChildren (handlebars.min.js?v=1624725822600:29)
    at e.compile (handlebars.min.js?v=1624725822600:28)
    at e.compileChildren (handlebars.min.js?v=1624725822600:29)
    at e.compile (handlebars.min.js?v=1624725822600:28)
    at e.compileChildren (handlebars.min.js?v=1624725822600:29)
    at e.compile (handlebars.min.js?v=1624725822600:28)
    at e.compileChildren (handlebars.min.js?v=1624725822600:29)
```

Comment: Nope @Nihal Chandwani